# Class structure or design pattern for a shared border between two cells

Tags: oop, data-structures, design-patterns, structure

This is more of a "best practice" or "best approach" kind of question; I was able to solve the core Problem myself, but I wonder how a situation like this should best be resolved.

Imagine a 2-dimensional board with a grid of square cells. Each cell is an independent instance of a class.

This would be the Pseudocode:

```
class Board {
    int width;
    int height;
    Array cells;
}

class Cell {
    Board parent;
    int x;
    int y;
    int value;
}
```

(To make the example a bit more clear: Imagine this is a Sudoku puzzle, with each cell holding a value.)

Now, while each `Cell` is independent, some `Cells` share a border. Let's say that this border is also it's own class, since it can be configured separately (for example, one cell's top border might be of a different color, style or thickness).

Now, if I extend the Pseudocode to accomodate for this:

```
class Cell {
    ...
    Array borders;
}

class CellBorder {
    Cell parent;
    int direction; // 0=top, 1=right, 2=bottom, 3=left
    Style style; // thickness, style, color, etc.
}
```

My Question is: Clearly, two connected `Cells` share a `Border` - what's the best way to deal with something like this?

- Where is the `Border` instance initially created? Inside the `Cell`? Outside the `Cell`, in the `Board` class?
- How would two `Cells` share a `Border`? Do they each have a pointer to the same instance, or two separate instances that just copy each other?
- What if a `Cell` is moved to a different position? Are all affected `Borders` reconstructed or existing instances swapped?
- If I want to configure a specific Border, how do I select it? By picking `Cell(x,y).rightBorder`? `Cell(x+1,y).leftBorder`? `Board.border(x,y,'right')`? (Ideally it shouldn't matter, but perhaps there is some benefit to one method over the other)
- Should `Borders` (and perhaps even `Cells`) be created in a factory?

My current solution, is to only have the "top" and "left" `Borders` in each `Cell`, while linking the "bottom" and "right" `Border` to the neighbors "top" and "left" `Borders` respectively.

But generally speaking, what would be a good and flexible approach here? Would the `Border` handling be relayed to the `Board` instead of the `Cells`? I'm sure this type of problem must be fairly common and has some best-practices or perhaps even a well-suited design pattern.

Comment: With your design, how do you display a bottom or right border for a cell located either on the bottom line or on the right column of a board ?

Comment: @Spotted In my specific case, I don't have to care about the outer bounds of the Board, so I was able to simply ignore them - but I was curious about a more generalized solution, since I want to clean that up. My solution was more of a "quick fix" until I had more time to do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: since you are looking for good practices in the object-oriented world, my answers will be oriented toward domain-driven design, object thinking and immutability.

> Where is the Border instance initially created? Inside the Cell? Outside the Cell, in the Board class?

It would advocate that a `Cell` to request an array of already constructed `CellBorder` when creating itself. Requesting every field for every border separately (each direction and style for each border) would clutter the `Cell` creation.

> How would two Cells share a Border? Do they each have a pointer to the same instance, or two separate instances that just copy each other?

If `CellBorder` is immutable, it doesn't matter if some instances are shared by multiple cells or not.
If `CellBorder` is mutable then prefer creation of new `CellBorder` for each `Cell` to avoid nasty side-effects if the `Board` (or any `Cell`) were to update some `CellBorder`.

> What if a Cell is moved to a different position? Are all affected Borders reconstructed or existing instances swapped?

Then the `Cell`'s coordinates are just changed. Which effect does it have on its borders ?

> If I want to configure a specific Border, how do I select it? By picking Cell(x,y).rightBorder? Cell(x+1,y).leftBorder? Board.border(x,y,'right')? (Ideally it shouldn't matter, but perhaps there is some benefit to one method over the other)

If `Cell` can't exist without being in a `Board`, makes sure to encapsulate the array of `Cell` inside the `Board` and add some behavior to the `Board` to change an existing cell's border. Example method call could be `board.ChangeBorder(x, y, newStyle)`

> Should Borders (and perhaps even Cells) be created in a factory?

They could be if you are hitting some performance issues when instanciating a `Board` with all of its `Cell`. In the case of a Sudoku (assuming 9x9) I don't think this should be needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1 :** The border class must be created in the board class. Imagine the relationship between the two Cells. Imagine that we split the board, border, and cell parts into layers. The base part will be the Board part. Then, the cells formed according to the border and border borders, which determine the cell parts, should come. Actually, the cells here are dynamic and should take values ​​according to the approaches of the border and board parts.

**Question 2 :** Sharing two Cell boundary should need two instances duplicating each other.

**Question 3 :** If a cell is purchased from a different one, the existing one must be replaced.

**Question 4 :** To change a particular plan, it is helpful to coordinate and assign a value to each boundary direction. E.g; Let the number of cells for y be 10. alphabetically; Values ​​such as a1+y,b2+y,c3+y,d4+y,e5+y can be given and in this way, interventionability can be made easy.

**Question 5 :** It should be created in terms of responsiveness and developability.

> Of course, my answers are a collection of my own approaches. I hope
> that will be useful.